# How to keep track of Test Case versus Test Plan

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, mstest, mtm

I can create a Test Plan in Microsoft Test Manager. In that plan, I can add Test Cases and execute them.

My issue is that whn someone gives me a Test Case number (ID), it is not possible for me to know in which Test Plan it was executed and if it passed the tests or not. Is there a way, to either :

- Know in which Test Plan the Test Case was executed
- Know the results of the last execution of the Test Case

I'm new to MTM and looking online didn't help me much as I seem to be the only one wondering about this (probably because there is an obvious solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible without some serious messing around with the TFS API right now.

Part of the problem is that internally test cases are stored as *work items* where test plans and test results are stored in completely different parts of the system with complex relationship structures. As a result, the built in query engine can't access them.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768487/mtm-12-web-feedback-allow-tester-to-view-multiple-test-plans has a request which is currently on the list of "we'll do this eventually" which would help. You can also join (if you aren't already a member) and add your own request or vote on those that you think would be helpful.

Comment: @phadaphunk - I know, it's a nuisance. There's a reason I'm building a chunk of extra interfacing by the API to be able to access this kind of data for myself. That takes pretty solid programming, though, and a lot of messing around in places Microsoft would really rather you didn't touch (which is why what I've done so far is kludgy as all get-out).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link i think it will useful for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282443.aspx

Comment: Yes but that doesnt helP on my issue

Comment: I think that @Anand's answer does explain it.  Look at the first item in the Q&A Section:   Q: Can I view the recent test results for an individual test case?  
A: Yes. Select the test case within a test suite and then choose to view the test details pane.   See the ensuing screenshot for explanation